# How to write an equivalent IF ELSE adhoc sql query in Snowflake

Tags: if-statement, return, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a Snowflake equivalent to the below T-SQL based adhoc query.

```
**T-SQL version**
Declare @i int = 0;

If(@i = 0)
   PRINT '0';
Else
 Begin
   PRINT '1'
   RETURN;
   PRINT '2'
 End


**Snowflake version**
Set i = 0;

If($i = 0)
   Select '0';
Else
 Begin
   Select '1'
   RETURN;
   Select '2'
 End
```

When I am running the Snowflake query from the Snowflake Web UI, I am getting an error as

> SQL compilation error : syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'IF'

I have searched the snowflake documentation and did not find helpful documentation for:

1. If Else
2. Begin End
3. Return

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snowflake does not support conditional T-SQL statements. It [does support conditional expressions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/expressions-conditional.html) within a query.

For conditional statement execution, consider using Snowflake's [stored procedures with embedded JavaScript](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html) if the use of conditional expressions is inadequate for your needs.

A very trivial example of a stored procedure, illustrating a conditional query execution upon call:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stored_proc_example(TEST_VALUE INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    // Declaring SQL statement(s) to execute later
    var command_1 = "SELECT 1";
    var command_2 = "SELECT 2";

    if (TEST_VALUE === 0) {

        var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: command_1 });
        var rs = stmt.execute();
        // Omitted: Perform logic with 'rs' rows to prepare a return value
        return '1';

    } else {

        var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: command_2 });
        var rs = stmt.execute();
        // Omitted: Perform logic with 'rs' rows to prepare a return value
        return '2';

    }
$$
;
```

Run as:

```sql
SET i=0;
CALL stored_proc_example($i);

SET i=1;
CALL stored_proc_example($i);
```

Comment: Thank you Kirby. This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake Scripting introduced anonymous block and [Branching constructs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch.html#working-with-branching-constructs):

```
DECLARE 
  i INT DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
  IF (i = 0) THEN
     RETURN 'zero';
  ELSE
     RETURN 'non-zero';
  END IF;
END;
```

or:

```
BEGIN
  LET i INT := 0;
   
  IF (i = 0) THEN
     RETURN 'zero';
  ELSE
     RETURN 'non-zero';
  END IF;
END;
```

Further reading: [Working with Variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html)

Comment: When I run these statements as-is in a blank worksheet the first throws error 'unexpected end' and the second throws error EOF. Is there missing context?

Comment: @gph Please run it using Snowsight instead of Classic Web UI - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try with snowflake scripting and change your accordingly

```
set
    stmt = $$
 begin
    let i := 1;
case when (i=0) then 
    return 0;
 when (i=1 ) then 
    return '1 ';
    else 
    return '2';
 end ;
end;
$$;
execute immediate $stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
      STUDENT_NAME AS "Student Name"
    , CASE
            WHEN GRADE ILIKE 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
            WHEN GRADE ILIKE 'B' THEN 'Good'
            WHEN GRADE ILIKE 'C' THEN 'Average'
            WHEN GRADE ILIKE 'D' THEN 'Poor'
            WHEN GRADE ILIKE 'F' THEN 'Fail'
            ELSE 'N/A'
      END AS "Grade"
FROM STUDENT
```

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake you can use `CASE WHEN` statements for this. [Here's the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html).

Comment: What about trying the IFF() function which is a "Single-level if-then-else expression":  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html Something like: Set i = 1; select iff($i = 0, 0, 1); - though I'm not quite sure how to get to the 2 value in your statement...

Comment: @MikeDonovan did you mean to comment on the OP? But either way, yes, that sounds like a valid option for this case!