# if condition in Snowflake procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

getting error with below if condition in Snowflake procedure

`if (col1 in ('a','b')) { //some condition };`

is there any way that we can construct if condition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error exactly you get?

Comment: `can not use IN operator to search for `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about JavaScript procedures, here is a list of JavaScript comparison and logical operators: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

You could use something like `col1 == 'a' or col1 == 'b'` as a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake procedure statement very different.

if you use javascript try

```js
if (col1 in ['a','b']) { //some condition };
```

you can see more doc [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html)

and like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524218/how-to-write-an-equivalent-if-else-adhoc-sql-query-in-snowflake)